# how can I keep a tunnel running in ngrok or automatically start tunnel when machine cuts on?

Tags: nginx

I would like to keep a ngrok tunnel running without having to constantly keep the command "ngrok http --domain=mydomain.com 80" going in the terminal. Is this possible? If so how would I go about doing this? Or how could I make this tunnel open automatically when the machine starts? Any suggestions will be appreciated, thank you.

tunnel only runs when the command is constantly running in the teminal.

Comment: There are plenty of resources available describing how to run a script on startup, as well as running scripts in the background. For example: https://itnext.io/how-to-run-your-scripts-on-startup-in-windows-8ae62a625f6c, https://askubuntu.com/questions/88091/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-background